# understanding return block in @connect decorator

Tags: react-redux, react-redux-form

I am going thru the react redux application and I came across @connect decorator. However, I find that in some scenarios, there is a return used inside the @connect, something like this:

```
@connect(() => {
     ....
    return { ..... };
})
```

I don't understand, what does the return do in this scenario?